# HTML: How to center a paragraph and image in a link?

Tags: html, css

```css
.brandingWrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 42px;
}

.apptitle {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'apptitle';
  vertical-align: center;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="brandingWrapper" href="/">
    <img class="applogo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Wikipedia%27s_W.svg/128px-Wikipedia%27s_W.svg.png?20220824035851" width="42" height="42" />
    <p class="apptitle">Appname</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

But this is what it looks like:

[image: img]

How can I center the text?

## Edit:

Sorry for the confusion. I want it vertically centered, so it is on the same height as the logo.

Comment: You cannot have a block element (`<p>`) inside an inline element (`<a>`).

Comment: `vertical:align` only work on inline-element. `<p>` is block element. convert `<p>`  to `<span>`

Comment: @moonwave99 — The `<a>` element hasn't been inline for a very long time. [It now has a transparent content model.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Comment: please clear vertical-center or horizontal center.

Comment: for horizontal center : add property  `justify-content: center;` on .brandingWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paragraphs have, by default, a significant `margin-top`. You need to reduce it.

```css
.brandingWrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 42px;
}

.apptitle {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'apptitle';
  vertical-align: center;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="brandingWrapper" href="/">
    <img class="applogo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Wikipedia%27s_W.svg/128px-Wikipedia%27s_W.svg.png?20220824035851" width="42" height="42" />
    <p class="apptitle">Appname</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parent div you have to add the following css code:

```
div{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

if you don't want to center horizontal just delete:

```
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

well there is so many ways to center elements
in your code you can center it by changing margin property for apptitle to this

```
.apptitle {
          font-size: 28px; 
          font-family: 'apptitle'; 
          vertical-align: center;
          color: black;
          margin-right:auto; 
          margin-left:auto; 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

We can enter the button by using `text-align:center`.

By setting the value of `text-align` property of parent div tag to the center. margin:auto- By setting the value of margin property to auto.

Answer (score -1):

You need two additional css properties in your `apptitle` class:

```css
...

.apptitle {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}
```

And you can remove `vertical-align: center;` because this will do nothing. Its invalid.